# query when object name is a URL

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I've written a JQ search that outputs the following, but I cannot work out how to get into the detail and extract specific information from this.

```
{
  "https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/revision_uid": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/user/37?_format=hal_json"
        },
        "type": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/rest/type/user/user"
        }
      },
      "uuid": [
        {
          "value": "d40684cf-2321-42d2-9194"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/uid": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/user/37?_format=hal_json"
        },
        "type": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/rest/type/user/user"
        }
      },
      "uuid": [
        {
          "value": "d40684cf-2321-42d2-9194"
        }
      ],
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_category": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/simplecategory?_format=hal_json"
        },
        "type": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/rest/type/taxonomy_term/tags"
        }
      },
      "uuid": [
        {
          "value": "3fef93d5-926a-41aa-95cb"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_part1_speaker": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/by/speakername?_format=hal_json"
        },
        "type": {
          "href": "https://www.example.org/rest/type/taxonomy_term/author"
        }
      },
      "uuid": [
        {
          "value": "fb6c806f-fa6a-4aa0-89ef"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I write a query that returns 'https://www.example.org/simplecategory?_format=hal_json'?

And I'd then want a similar query that returns 'https://www.example.org/by/speakername?_format=hal_json'

So `jq '._embedded'` gets me the data above.

I've then tried various combinations to get to the value of  `https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_category`.
- `jq '._embedded.https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_category` - but of course the URL has special characters in it.

- `jq .["https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_category"]`
- `jq ."https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_category$"`

I've also messed around with some of JQs built in functions, like flatten and to_entries, from_entries.  I've also tried regular expressions but my efforts return `Cannot iterate over null (null)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'll add to the question.  Really appreciate whoever downvoted this already - really nice - thank you.

Comment: `jq '.["https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/field_category"][0]._links.self.href' file` produces `"https://www.example.org/simplecategory?_format=hal_json"`

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail - that works!  (and similarly for the other query I needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I write a query that returns 'https://www.example.org/simplecategory?_format=hal_json'?

If you want to specify the top-level key explicitly, the follow-on query would be:

```
.["https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/revision_uid"][]
| ._links.self.href
```

That is, the entire query would be:

```
._embedded
| .["https://www.example.org/rest/relation/node/recording/revision_uid"][]
| ._links.self.href
```

> And I'd then want a similar query

An alternative to specifying the top-level key explicitly might be to select the href of interest from the array of all of them:

```
 ._embedded
 | [.[][]._links.self.href]
```

This would yield:

```
[
  "https://www.example.org/user/37?_format=hal_json",
  "https://www.example.org/user/37?_format=hal_json",
  "https://www.example.org/simplecategory?_format=hal_json",
  "https://www.example.org/by/speakername?_format=hal_json"
]
```